# How to convert .fits file/ astropy table to pandas df and reverse?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, astropy, fits

I need to frequently convert pandas df to .fits files and also the reverse - I am given .fits files for which is easier for me to process them as pandas dfs. What is the most straightforward way for doing the conversions between these file types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# 1.)  how to convert a pandas df 
# (or almost any ascii data file) to astropy table
# and save the table as .fits file

from astropy.table import Table
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('some_file.dat', delim_whitespace=True, skiprows=7, names=['A', 'B', 'C'])

t = Table.from_pandas(df)
t.write('some_file.fits')




# 2.)  how to convert a fits file (or astropy table) to pandas df

dat = Table.read('some_file.fits')
df = dat.to_pandas()



# 3.)  it is like 1.) but without a df as intermediate step - 
# how to read a csv/ascii file directly as astropy table
# and save it as .fits   

table = Table.read('some_file.dat', format='ascii.tab')
table.write('some_file.fits', overwrite=True)
```